# Hyper-V Guest OS sees partition as RAW

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have a 2TB array that is partitioned into a 100GB C: and 100GB D: drives. The C: drive was a Server 2008R2 that was P2V and is now running as a guest on a Windows 2012R2 host. The Host OS sees the D: drive fine. However, the now VM 2008R2 server is showing that same D: drive as RAW and is unable to see the data. Any ideas on why that is and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not understanding this. How is it that both the host and the VM have access to this drive/array? Is this a disk array in the host? If so, how are you mapping it to the VM?

Comment: @joeqwerty: The physical server has a RAID 1 with 2x2TB drives. Initially, I had Server2008R2 installed on the physical machine to a C: partition and then created a data partition D: on the disks as well. I then P2V'd the 2008R2 server to a VHDX. Installed 2012R2 onto the physical server to a new C: partition but didn't touch the D: partition. The new 2012R2 host can see the Data on the D: just fine. However, running the now VM of 2008R2 it sees that D: partition as RAW and is not able to access the info on it. Is there something special I need to do for it to see that D: partition?

Comment: Uhm, what?  Not sure what your doing, but it doesn't make a lot of sense.  You can't have two instances of windows using the same volume/filesystem unless you done some very specific clustering setup.  If your Hyper-V OS can see the volume/filesystem then your Guest should not be able to touch it.  What did you do to try to map the physical volume into your VM?

Comment: @Zoredache: You may be right and that is my problem. I am not doing anything special to map the partition to the guest. Perhaps it is showing up due to the P2V process and is just a remnant of when it was a physical host? Maybe I need to share out the D: from the current host and then map the guest OS to it?

Comment: I am working with 2 partitions on a single disk. Does that help clear this up?

Answer (score 0):

You, like almost everybody else who's new to this area, are confusing disk sharing and file sharing.  Here's another question where I tried to explain the difference between these two:

[File Sharing using Hyper-V Shared VHDX](https://serverfault.com/questions/665182/file-sharing-using-hyper-v-shared-vhdx/665386#665386)